# Cannot import mysql database in vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

My problem with the code is that i can't really restore a database which i saved 
from my desktop ... how can i do this? is there something with my directory?

```
    Private Sub btnRestore_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As   System.EventArgs) Handles btnRestore.Click

    Dim file As String
    opd.Filter = "SQL Dump File (*.sql)|*.sql|All files (*.*)|*.*"
    If opd.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        file = opd.FileName
        Dim myProcess As New Process()
        myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"
        myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        myProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.17/bin"
        myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
        myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        myProcess.Start()
        Dim myStreamWriter As StreamWriter = myProcess.StandardInput
        Dim mystreamreader As StreamReader = myProcess.StandardOutput
        myStreamWriter.WriteLine("mysql -u root  -h localhost ""ceams"" > """ + file + """ ")
        myStreamWriter.Close()
        myProcess.WaitForExit()
        myProcess.Close()
        MsgBox("Database Restoration Successfully!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Restore")
    End If
```

My problem with the code is that i can't really restore a database

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please be more specifif. What errors do you get?

Comment: my database name is ceams in the connection module is there any possiblity that i can import any sql file that corresponds my queries in my original database "ceams"